# Want to Include CKeditor in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ng2-admin theme. I have created two folder Landingpage1 and LandingPage2 in **src/app/pages** folder structure.

Now I have created two separate module in two separate folder:

**1. landingPage1.module.ts**

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgaModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,  
        CKEditorModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        LandingPage1,
        Ckeditor,
    ]
})
```

**2. landingPage2.module.ts**

```
  @NgModule({
    imports:[
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgaModule,
        CommonModule,
        CKEditorModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations:[
         LandingPage2,
         Ckeditor,
    ]
})
```

When I using the Ckeditor in two component file then I getting following error:

**Error: Type Ckeditor is part of the declarations of 2 modules: LandingPage1Module and LandingPage2Module! Please consider moving Ckeditor to a higher module that imports LandingPage1Module and LandingPage2Module. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes Ckeditor then import that NgModule in LandingPage1Module and LandingPage2Module.**

I have imported Ckeditor on app.module.ts file but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Ckeditor` from `declarations` in `landingPage1.module.ts` and `landingPage2.module.ts`.

Just keep it inside where you are importing those 2 modules , if `app.module.ts` then add there.

---

Proper solution to this is create a `commonModule` named `EditorCommonModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CKEditorModule
    ],
    exports: [
        CKEditorModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class EditorCommonModule { }
```

Then just import this `EditorCommonModule` wherever you need the ckEditor.

Remove `CKEditorModule` and `Ckeditor` from every where.

Comment: Yes I have removed Ckeditor from app.module.ts file.

Comment: For One Landing1 page is working fine but when I redirect to Landing page2. it gives me error.

Comment: I am not adding the module any where. I just put the code on pages.routing.ts file

**
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'reviewForm1',
    loadChildren: 'app/pages/landingPage1/landingPage1.module#LandingPage1'
  },
  {
    path: 'reviewForm1',
    loadChildren: 'app/pages/landingPage2/landingPage1.module#LandingPage2'
  },
];**

Comment: @ManeeshRao, please update your code as I mentioned proper solution.

Comment: @ManeeshRao, just remove `Ckeditor` from `declarations`, and try , that might work.

Comment: I am getting this error "Error: Can't export directive Ckeditor from EditorCommonModule as it was neither declared nor imported!"

Comment: We even can only export module. Import looks redundant if we don't use it in EditorCommonModule. But we already have EditorModule, so we do not need EditorCommonModule

Comment: @ManeeshRao, just remove Ckeditor from declarations, and try , that might work , have you tried this ?

Comment: True, I have exports the EditorCommonModule. Now there is no any error but editor is not showing.

Comment: @ManeeshRao, Now need your code on plnkr or jsfiddle to debug.

Comment: @ManeeshRao, woow glad to hear that, was that becaus of my answer?

Comment: Yes, Can you please tell me how to show and hide the editor tool bar by Angular2 because I want to hide editor tool bar when page is loaded.

Comment: @ManeeshRao, thanks thanks , then will you please accpet the answer?